# Why is the static variable initialized with redeclaration of static variable outside the class? Can't we just initialize it instead of redeclaring it?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Box
{
   public:
      static int objectCount;
}

// Initialize static member of class Box
int Box::objectCount = 0;
```

Comment: Primitive types like `int` actually _can be_ initialized at the point of declaration of `static` class members.

Comment: That was an omission on the part of earlier C++ standard, which has been fixed in a later edition of the standard.

Comment: Huh? To counter the earlier comments, GCC rejects in-class initialisation with "error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member", and clang does with "error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line". Both regardless of `-std=*` options. Which standard supposedly allows this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you mix up the declaration and the definition of a variable.

The declaration just tells the compiler a name.
So in your case:

```
class Box
{
    public:
        static int objectCount;
};
```

This just tells the compiler that there is a variable with the name `objectCount`.
But now you still need a definition.

```
int Box::objectCount = 0;
```

Simplified the definition is what the linker needs.
So as a simple rule static member variables must be declared in the class and then defined outside of it.